# Entries of a matrix represented as a graph

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation, definition, bipartite-graphs

I have to go through [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-21.2.379), where I encountered this definition:

> The pattern of a matrix A is a bipartite graph with a node for each
>   row and each column and an edge connecting row node i to column node j
>   whenever $a_{ij} \neq 0$. A matrix B is said, by abuse of language, to
>   have a partial pattern of A if its pattern is a partial graph of the
>   pattern of A (same nodes, subset of the edges). This is equivalent to
>   $a_{ij} = 0 \Rightarrow b_{ij} = 0$. The matrix A is called connected
>   if its pattern is a connected graph. In a graph two nodes are called
>   neighbours if there is an edge connecting them. By abuse of language
>   we extend this terminology to rows and columns (and even row
>   multipliers and column multipliers).

From my understanding i drew this picture:

[image]

But I dont seem to get the  "by the abuse of language"-Part at the very end. Because in that proof below the author speaks about neighbours of entries of a vector (after the formula). But that matrix/vector-entry cannot have a neighbour, because it is an edge of a graph, which cannot have a neighbor. It makes no sense to me.

[image]